# Delete from table using columns with null values Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-delete

I have an automatic process to make incremental inserts based on defined primary keys of the table. In a few tables, the primary key has null values and we cannot make anything to solve it at the root, so we have to deal with it.

Once the primary keys of the table are obtained, we run a query to delete records as follows:

```
DELETE FROM table
USING stg_table
WHERE table.pk_1 = stg_table.pk_1 AND table.pk_2 = stg_table.pk_2
```

This works except if some value in the `pk_1` or `pk_2` is null. I have done the following to solve it:

```
DELETE FROM table
USING stg_table
WHERE NVL(table.pk_1, 'null') = NVL(stg_table.pk_1, 'null')
```

However, this only works if the `pk_1` is `VARCHAR`, otherwise, it will fail.

I could modify my automated script and get the type of each column and depending on that pass a different value to the NVL function, but I was wondering if there is any way of achieving correctly the deletion using just Snowflake.

Comment: Why use a join at all to handle deletes? There is no relationship that can be established between records in separate tables where the values are null in the joined column. Just delete records from the staging table containing null. These records can't be used to relate to anything useful if their primary key has null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `NULL` values to match, you can use:

```
DELETE FROM table
USING stg_table
WHERE (table.pk_1 = stg_table.pk_1 OR table.pk_1 IS NULL AND stg_table.pk_1 IS NULL) AND
      (table.pk_2 = stg_table.pk_2 OR table.pk_2 IS NULL AND stg_table.pk_2 IS NULL)
```

Or, use `EQUAL_NULL()`, Snowflake's NULL-safe comparison operator:

```
DELETE FROM table
USING stg_table
WHERE EQUAL_NULL(table.pk_1, stg_table.pk_1) AND
      EQUAL_NULL(table.pk_2, stg_table.pk_2);
```

All that said, primary keys are *never* `NULL` -- by the definition of SQL.  And it is really rare to create databases where a `NULL` value in two different tables are supposed to match.

Answer (score 0):

The `IS DISTINCT FROM` is null-safe operator and it allow to compare tuples:

```
DELETE FROM table
USING stg_table
WHERE (table.pk_1,table.pk_2) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM (stg_table.pk_1, stg_table.pk_2);
```